# Unable to iterate object type "int" error without iterating through an integer

Tags: python-2.7, function, int, iteration

```
ans = raw_input("Please set the starting juvenile population (or type same to leave it unchanged):")
cont, num = setGen0Check(ans, 0)
if cont == 1:
    if num == 1:
        juvenilePop = round(float(ans), 3)
else:
    invalidInput()
    y = setGen0(x, y, z)

def setGen0Check(ans, bounds):
    cont = 1
    cont2 = 1
    num = (numOrStrCheck(46, 57, ans))
    if ans.lower() != "same" and num == 0:
        invalidInput()
        count = 0
    elif len(ans) == 0:
        invalidInput()
        cont = 0
    elif num == 1:
        if float(ans) < 0:
            invalidInput()
            cont = 0
        if bounds == 1:
            cont2 = setGen0bounds(0, 1, ans)
        if bounds == 2:
            cont2 = setGen0bounds(15, 25, ans)
    if cont == 1 and cont2 == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    return num

def numOrStrCheck(lowerBnd, higherBnd, ans):
    for i in ans:
        b = ord(i)
        if b > higherBnd or b < lowerBnd:
            return 0
    return 1
```

Whenever I give it an input I get the error:

> `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

with a line referance:

> `cont, num = setGen0Check(ans, 0)`

It was working until I decided to allow for string inputs (requiring my passing of whether or not it is a number into the same function the input was taken).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `raw_input`.

Function `setGen0Check` returns a single integer value. When executing the statement: `cont, num = setGen0Check(ans, 0)`, interpreter tries to iterate over the returned value, because it needs 2 values to assign to `cont` and  `num`. Then, an exception is raised, because it can't iterate over int.

Please post full tracebacks when asking questions like that, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from

```
for i in ans:

for i in range(ans):
```

Integer is not iterable object.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will keep that in mind in the future.